# Short novel about a generation ship run by a group of elders

Tags: story-identification, novel, generation-ship

It's a sci-fi/fantasy novel I read some years ago and I can't find it.
I don't know the title or the author.

It's about a multi generation star ship that is run by a team of 10-12 elders. They are running the ship in turns, while the rest of the elders are in cryogenic states.

The story is about the rest of the population that forget, over some hundreds of years, what is all about. They develop strange rituals that make no sense; around the ship protocols, and about interaction with elders. They lose the information regarding what elders are and somehow everything starts to go towards religious rituals that have no meaning and real value in the ship protocols. But this is the level of knowing for the rest of the population.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year would you have read this?  ("Some years ago" isn't very specific.)  Do you recall the cover art or the names of any of the characters?

Comment: What kind of culture did the passengers develop?  Was it based on an older Earth culture, or did it incorporate some knowledge of the ship?  (Did the passengers even still know they were on a ship?)

Answer (score 11):

Stephen Baxter's **[Mayflower II](https://shortform.livejournal.com/8666.html)**

From the review linked above:

> Five generation starships set out from their base, Port Sol, each carrying one **pharaoh** and a couple of hundred colonists (for the
> Coalition isn't picky about who it makes examples of). Rusel is one of
> the colonists due to be left behind, but at the last minute a vacancy
> opens up.

> So the ship's Pharaoh, Andres, institutes an iron order, a literal
> social contract designed to ensure stability over twenty millennia.
> Or, in her own words: "there will be no conceptual breakthrough
> on my watch!" (p.35)
>
> To this end she uses some of her limited resources to establish a
> **cadre of other immortals, in an attempt to provide continuity, memory.**
> It doesn't matter, she reasons, if the transients forget; as long as
> they are stewarded by Elders then they can reach their destination
> safely and free. Rusel, of course, becomes one of the new immortals,
> eventually the only one, and it is through his eyes that we see the
> long march of years.

> Things change over time, of course. The solutions that Andres so
> carefully puts in place break down (or looking at it another way,
> succeed too well), and too the journey of the ship is taking place
> over evolutionary time. Baxter suggests that in such an environment,
> where maintenance of the status quo is the most important thing, the
> selection pressure would be away from intelligence; and so, gradually,
> the transient population changes. The meaning behind their tasks
> vanishes. The cleaning and repairing become secondary sexual
> characteristics, like a peacocks' tail or the antlers of a stag:
> something by which individuals indicate their reproductive fitness to
> a mate. **Innovation and curiosity are selected against. By the end of
> the story, the transients have become a perfect, instinctive starship
> crew.**